# Substituting arbitrary number of characters with regexp in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string with sequence of digits inside - they are preceeded by some special prefix and limited by the non-numeric symbol, like this:

```
Vechny Zov,Sholokhov1970.IBSN:123456-m15p243
```

I'm curious how to substitute this subsequence of digits with sequence of asterisks of the same length:

```
Vechny Zov,Sholokhov1970.IBSN:******-m15p243
```

other digits should not be affected. This could be easily done with the help of variable-width look behind, like this:

```
replace /(?<=IBSN\:\d*)\d/, '*'
```

but I found suddenly that PHP does not allow lookbehinds of arbitrary (even limited) width.

Is there any workaround? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you want to use `-` in the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [\G anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) (assert position where last match ended) combined with a lookbehind:

```
((?<=IBSN:)|(?!^)\G)\d
```

`(?!^)` The negative lookahead checks, that `\G` does not match the start.

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zB6tW4/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!\d.*IBSN:.*)\d(?=\d*[-.,].+$)
```

Try this.This relaces the exact amount of *.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/18

Comment: @there was a new line character in your regex

Comment: Nice trick with using negative lookahead! If I understand correctly it will only work wrong if the prefix does not exist in the string at all %)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex,

```
(?:(.*IBSN:|-.*)|^(?:(?!ISBN).)*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aM3lT9/4)

Comment: Quite interesting feature, this `(*SKIP)` etc. - thank you since I learned something new!